# Error remind for boost: could not find "vswhere"

Tags: c++, boost

I am a newer to deploy boost for my project. When I try to construct the boost engine after downloading and decompressing it, the error information below was returned:

```
D:\Program Files\boost_1_81_0\boost_1_81_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local
could not find "vswhere"
Call_If_Exists "..\bin\VCVARS32.BAT"
###
### Using 'msvc' toolset.
###
```

Because this error, the rest stages for executing b2 was failed to operate. According to another existed question relative with this, MinGC is required to be installed beforehand. However, I found that I have installed MinGC and correctly set the environment variables.
Additionally, after I realised that the bootstrap command can be executed by specifying an existed complier, I modified my command to

```
bootstrap gcc
```

but it returned another error with lots of syntax and variable errors:

```
...
execnt.cpp:67:10: fatal error: versionhelpers.h: No such file or directory
   67 | #include <versionhelpers.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
jam.cpp: In function 'int guarded_main(int, char**)':
jam.cpp:185:22: error: 'environ' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'union'?
  185 | # define use_environ environ
      |                      ^~~~~~~
jam.cpp:488:37: note: in expansion of macro 'use_environ'
  488 |         var_defines( root_module(), use_environ, 1 );
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
pathsys.cpp: In function 'char* executable_path(const char*)':
pathsys.cpp:381:54: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strcmp'?
  381 |     return ( !ret || ret == sizeof( buf ) ) ? NULL : strdup( buf );
      |                                                      ^~~~~~
      |                                                      strcmp
...
```

And finally, it still failed:

```
D:\Program Files\boost_1_81_0\boost_1_81_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive D is Lenovo
 Volume Serial Number is 5806-0F8D

 Directory of D:\Program Files\boost_1_81_0\boost_1_81_0\tools\build\src\engine

File Not Found

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
```

Because this is my first time to install and use boost, I really hope anyone to help me solve this problem or give me any advice for fixing it. Many thanks!!

Comment: It's true that, very often, trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc or boost, into a foreign operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix code, turns out to be a major, major time sink. Even experienced developers will struggle with this, not to mention those who are new to C++. Most of the time it takes much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me just an hour and a half, last time. Now, I'd just buy a Lenovo laptop with preloaded Linux. How much time did you already spend on this?

Comment: By `MinGC` did you mean `MinGW`? There's a specific target for it. e.g.: `bootstrap mingw`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't mean to offend, and I do mean it sincerely, but don't be disingenuous. C++ and C++ build tools are quite well supported on Windows these days. It's a fact that as developers we have to support multiple platforms, and Windows is ubiquitous in the Desktop space, so let's not fight it. As the late Rodney King said, "can we all get along?"

Comment: You, @CássioRenan, and anyone else for that matters -- I hereby give everyone my complete enforsement to try to offend me in the worst way possible. I'm a big boy. I can handle it. Sticks and stones. Someone else's words will never hurt me. Now, with these formalities out of the way: isn't it curious how I never read anything of this sort, from anyone else, who's in an opposite situation: struggling with the same sorts of problems on Linux? Why's that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not sure what you mean, there are literally [over a thousand](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Blinux%5D+build+error) questions about build errors on linux. And before you use the "no true scottsman" fallacy and say that those aren't real linux issues, keep in mind that this question itself is really probably just about the OP using the incorrect target for their build.

Comment: You'll have a very long and exhaustive search, @CássioRenan, to find a comparable question to this one, for Linux. This is for the very simple reason that there's rarely a need to build Boost itself, on Linux, manually. It's already built. The closest that's comparable are the rare queries from someone who needs to build or install a prebuilt package for one Linux distribution, but on a different one. Someone has a OEM binary package built for some 6-yr old LTS release, and they want it running on the current Fedora. But that gets asked maybe once a year. Qs like this one: a few every week.

Comment: There are also prebuilt binaries of boost for Windows... It's not some magic thing that only linux has. It's as easy as running `Install-Package boost`.

Comment: Consider using package manager for Windows, like [choco](https://chocolatey.org/).